# Aligning NavBar Right cause NavBar to disable

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float, alignment, right-align

I'm trying to right align my NavBar, but whenever I add float:right, the navbar moves to the right, but seems to become disabled.

See here: goo.gl/46yUrt

Code:

```
/**
 * 4.2 Navigation
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 45px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
}
```

I'm using a custom modified version of the TwentyThirteen theme.

Ideally, I'd like to have the menu beside the logo at the top, both centered.

Comment: I'm not sure what information users may need, so please let me know if you need something else.

Comment: div.content-entry seems to shift up when I add float:right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float:right seems to be positioning the nav bar beneath another element. Adding z-index:1 fixes that, but you'll still have to adjust the position of the bar.

Comment: I found a Float:Left inside of .site-header .logo-align which I removed. In doing so, I seem to have resolved the issue. Now, I just need to position the Menu beside the logo.

Comment: Ended up having to use the z-index anyways. Thanks!